# Открытие файла в проводнике

Tags: unity3d

Мне необходимо открыть файл из приложения андроид (т.е. чтобы в приложении появилось меню с выбором нужного проводника, и в проводнике чтобы можно было выбрать файл определённого формата).

Answer (score 0):

Можете воспользоваться готовыми решениями. Например, [Runtime File Browser](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/gui/runtime-file-browser-113006?_ga=2.202013715.323583123.1615819285-2030944337.1613126586)

Также есть [скрипт](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel.html):

```cs
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

public class OpenFilePanelExample : EditorWindow
{
    [MenuItem("Example/Overwrite Texture")]
    static void Apply()
    {
        Texture2D texture = Selection.activeObject as Texture2D;
        if (texture == null)
        {
            EditorUtility.DisplayDialog("Select Texture", "You must select a texture first!", "OK");
            return;
        }

        string path = EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel("Overwrite with png", "", "png");
        if (path.Length != 0)
        {
            var fileContent = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
            texture.LoadImage(fileContent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: К сожалению такое решение мне не подходит. Мне необходимо это сделать в приложении андроид
 (```EditorUtility``` работает только в редакторе)

Comment: @Lesh воспользуйтесь плагином, он разве не работает?

Comment: Он работает, но он рисует собственный проводник, а мне нужно, чтобы функция вызывала отдельную программу (проводник), в которой можно выбрать файл.